# Python: Write stdout to log file; output is hexadecimal not ascii

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, stdout

I'm working on a script to call an executable for i/o files.  I'm using subprocess and trying to shell out the exe and the stdout to a log file.  Problem is I would like to output a simple ascii file and I'm getting a hexadecimal file.  Just really learning to program python (or any language for that matter) so, I'm assuming there some type of formatting I can do but I just don't get it.  I've done a fair bit of searching on this site and others but I haven't anything like what I'm using subprocess for.  The "outRadcorr" is what I need help on the most...Any ideas?  More code on request.

## Import system modules

```
import os, sys, string, traceback, time, datetime
import params
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
```

...some code here.....

## Write stdout to log file

```
rad_log_file = open(dsFolder + '\\radcorr.log', 'w')

# loop through the files in raw file list to run radiometric correction
for rawfiles in rawFolderList:

    # Define the file base
    rawBase = rawfiles.split(".")[0]
    print ('\nProcessing file: %s \n')%( rawBase )

    # define variables from raw file to process radcorr
    radFile = rawfiles
    pixFile = ('%s.pix')%( rawBase )
    attFile = ('%s.att')%( rawBase )

    # create windose bat file function
    def rad_bat_writer( radcorr_bat ):
        with open(dsFolder + '\\radcorr.bat', 'a') as rad_bat_file:
            rad_bat_file.write(radcorr_bat + '\n')

    # grab radcor input/output files and run radcorr.exe
    radcorr = ('C:\\itres\\bin\\radcorr.exe -f 1 -j 100 -g 50 -s -1 -n -1 %s %s %s -i '+ rawFolder + '\%s,rb -o ' + radFolder + '\%s -a ' \
    + radFolder + '\%s -c C:\\itres\\rad_cal_files\\%s -I 0 -v 0 -r Y -R Y -^^ 2') %( sum,scatter,shift,radFile,pixFile,attFile,rad_prefix )
    # print out radcorr command
    print radcorr
    # Execute radcorr and write stdout
    outRadcorr = Popen("{};".format(radcorr), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in outRadcorr.stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        rad_log_file.write(line)

    # write output to log
    rad_bat_writer( radcorr )

# Close out exe and log files
outRadcorr.wait()
rad_log_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm confused... radcorr.exe is outputing binary to stdout and you want to change it to a text form? What is printed on the screen? ... and rad_log_file is not text?

Comment: You write the same thing to the screen and the log file. How do you view the log file to see that it is "hexadecimal". What do you mean by the term "hexadecimal"?

Comment: use `r'C:\itres\bin\radcorr.exe -f 1 -j 100 -g 50 -s -1 -n -1 {sum} {scatter} {shift} -i {radpath},rb -o {pixpath} -a {radFolder}\{attFile} -c {rad_prefix_path} -I 0 -v 0 -r Y -R Y -^^ 2'.format(**vars())`, where `radpath = os.path.join(rawFolder, radFile)`, `pixpath = os.path.join(radFolder, pixFile)`, and `rad_prefix_path = os.path.join(r'C:\itres\rad_cal_files', rad_prefix)`.

Comment: Do you see `'\xe2\x98\x83'` instead of `☃`?

Comment: UltraEdit displays a file in hex view if it contains 2 or more NUL bytes, i.e. bytes with value 0. Text files do not contain NUL bytes. Text files usually contain only characters with a hexadecimal value >= 0x20 (space), carriage return (0x0D), line-feed (0x0A), horizontal tab (0x09), sometimes form-feed (0x0C). In UltraEdit there is **View - Views/Lists - ASCII Table** which shows the first 32 bytes of the ASCII table (control characters) with their abbreviations. Check your output file for NUL bytes. Are you should not writing first strings in ASCII/ANSI into the file and later in UTF-16?

Answer (score 0):

I was using UltraEdit to view the file, which you can view hex files in.  I was not looking in hex mode.  I might be confusing the terminology here.  File looks normal in NotePad/NotePad++/WordPad etc.  As I ran the script in debug mode, I could hit the loop file by file.  First two files (1GB/file), the output log looked fine.  Once the radcorr.log file was over 10kb, I change from a normal ascii output to this binary file viewed that looked hex.  I can't post images yet, but just google ultraedit hexadecimal.

Still not sure why it moved to this format.  Finally, output size was 45kb.  I change to view/edit hex mode in UltraEdit and it looks fine.  Just wanted to get it out there to see if others had any ideas why when I specified the log to be 'w' and not 'wb', for instance.

I do appreciate all you help.  @J.F. Sebastian I'll have to test the code you posted, probably help fix potential bugs down the road.